# Adding arrows pointing to subfigures in figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subfloats, tikzmark

I am working in a two-column format and have a figure that contains multiple subfigures. What I would like to do is to create arrows outside the subfigures which point to specific things within each subfigure. I have attached a rough drawing below which better explains what I would like to do.

Is such a construction possible in LaTeX? I could always do this by editing the arrows in Photoshop and then uploading it to Tex as one combined figure, but I am trying to avoid this if possible.

[image]

Comment: Probably you can do things like that with Ti*k*Z and the [`tikzmarks`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark?lang=en) package. But you should really post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we can better understand your problem.

Comment: For example, are you really using subfigures (floats) or just calling them subfigures?  Floats may wind up on another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example using the `tikzmark` library.

**(1)** Add `\tikzmark{<unique name>}` after each (sub) image.

**(2)** Draw arrows between the marks adding appropriate `x` and `y` shifts to the start and end of the arrow. The origin will be in the lower right corner.

The `tikzmark` library uses the `pic` coordinate system, so  the marks are called using `pic cs: name`. For example  `(pic cs:a)`.

The library `calc`  allow the notation `+(< xshift >, < yshift >)` to refer to a point from the origin.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark} % needed <<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% ONLY dumy text


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
    1.  \kant[1]
    
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}\tikzmark{a}
                
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-b}\tikzmark{b}
            
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-c}\tikzmark{c}
    \end{center}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[arrows=->,black,ultra thick]  ( $ (pic cs:b) +(6mm,20mm) $ ) --   ( $ (pic cs:a) +(-10mm,10mm) $ );
        \draw[arrows=->,red,ultra  thick]   ( $ (pic cs:b) +(6mm,8mm) $ ) --    ( $ (pic cs:b) +(-10mm,5mm) $ );
        \draw[arrows=->,black,ultra thick]  ( $ (pic cs:b) +(6mm,8mm) $ ) --    ( $ (pic cs:a) +(-10mm,5mm) $ );
        \draw[arrows=->,blue,ultra thick]   ( $ (pic cs:b) +(6mm,4mm) $ ) --    ( $ (pic cs:c) +(-26mm,9mm) $ );
        
        \draw ( $ (pic cs:c) +(0mm,0mm) $ ) circle[radius=5pt]; % show the origin
        \node[anchor=north] at ( $ (pic cs:c) +(-1ex,-1ex) $ ){Origin of mark c};% show the origin
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    2.  \kant[2-4]
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```